# Flutter: Set CupertinoTimerPicker value with a button

Tags: flutter

I'm using a 'CupertinoTimerPicker' widget and I'm trying to assign it's current value by pressing a button. However, assigning a new value to 'initialTimerDuration' doesn't seem to change the UI.

Here's my code:

```html
// the time picker
CupertinoTimerPicker(
  mode: CupertinoTimerPickerMode.hm,
  alignment: Alignment.center,
  initialTimerDuration: _dateClock,
  backgroundColor: themeColor,
  onTimerDurationChanged: (value) => _dateClock = value,
),

// the button that's supposed to set the time picker value

ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: () => {
    setState(() {
      _dateClock = Duration(hours: 15, minutes: 10);
    });
  },
  child: const Text('Now'),
),
```

SetState triggers a 'build' call which means the time picker should be rebuilt and use the newly assigned '_dateClock. So I don't know what's causing the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't resets because `CupertinoTimerPicker` is a `StatefulWidget`. It preserves it's state. To make it's state change, you can use instance of [Global Key](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GlobalKey-class.html) and change it to a new `GlobalKey` which will force it to redraw.

```dart
  var globalKey = GlobalKey();

// the time picker
CupertinoTimerPicker(
  key: globalKey,
  mode: CupertinoTimerPickerMode.hm,
  alignment: Alignment.center,
  initialTimerDuration: _dateClock,
  backgroundColor: themeColor,
  onTimerDurationChanged: (value) => _dateClock = value,
),

// the button that's supposed to set the time picker value

ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: () => {
    setState(() {
      _dateClock = Duration(hours: 15, minutes: 10);
      globalKey = GlobalKey();
    });
  },
  child: const Text('Now'),
),
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me solve the problem, and also for teaching me about the key property!